# Running a macro from XLSM file to XLSX File in Power Automate Desktop

Tags: excel, vba, power-automate-desktop

Hi I am a bit new to this
I am downloading one XLS file from the internet and it saves in a particular folder
Now I have XLSM file which i have in that folder that XLSM file contains a script to work on any active-workbook
When I manually open the file I can run the macro but when power automate opens the file it doesnt show any macro
I am stuck on this

Any Help Would Work,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Power Automate cannot run VBA code. You must create an Office Script and call that against your newly downloaded workbook (which MUST be in a format Excel-online can open). See my page on Office Script for some pointers:
https://jkp-ads.com/articles/excel-office-script-examples.asp

Comment: Its not a vba code that i want to run i found a work-around this so I am not nesting the excel under a new process that seemed to work for me and then i recorded how to run the macro which i want

Comment: You mentioned "that XLSM file contains a script". Since xlsm files can only contain either XL4 macro code (very unlikely) or VBA code, I assumed you wanted to run VBA code. an Office Script isn't part of a workbook and can be run against any workbook from Power Automate.

Comment: Maybe me I miscommunicated but yea I have a macro file which has a code to run on any active workbook
But thank you clarifying